# Как вернуть размер изображения в байтах?

Tags: java

Задача: разбить изображение на несколько частей по 200кб. Чтобы знать, сколько должно быть таких частей, нужно знать размер изображения.
Есть ли что-то вроде sizeOf, только применимое для BufferedImage?
Я думал насчёт ширина * высота * глубина кодирования, но в изображение на деле весит больше, чем это значение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изначально вы должны записать ваш файл в память или временный файл. Вот один из вариантов.

```
BufferedImage img = YOUR_IMAGE_THERE

ByteArrayOutputStream tmp = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(img, "png", tmp);
tmp.close();
Integer contentLength = tmp.size();
```

Answer (score 1):

Получаем размер изображения в байтах:

```
BufferedImage image = /* */;
int sizeInBytes = image.getData().getDataBuffer().getSize();
```

Или с помощью примера в другом ответе, можно будет узнать размер изображения в конкретном формате, в котором вы его сохраните.